# Expressions sequence in OR query of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

reading the documentations of OR queries of MongoDB the syntax of OR is :

```
Syntax: { $or: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> }, ... , { <expressionN> } ] }
```

The thing I didn't understand is the sequence in which theses expression executes. i.e

get documents matching expression-1 if nothing is found get documents matching expression-2 ect ... Is it true that expression execute one after other or ?

and what does it mean: "
When using indexes with $or queries, remember that each clause of an $or query will execute in parallel."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular order to a queries execution whether it be:

```
db.col.find({ name: 's', c: 1 });
```

Or:

```
db.col.find({$or: [{name: 's'}, {c: 1}]})
```

In an `$or` MongoDB will effectively make x queries based on the number of conditions you have in your `$or`, return a result for each clause, merge duplicates and then return the result (simply put). Due to this behaviour MongoDB can actually use multiple indexes for an `$or` clause, and at the minute only an `$or` clause.

This is important to note when making compound indexes. Indexes do require a certain structure to the query sometimes to work at optimal pace. As such if you have a compound index of:

```
{name: 1, c: 1}
```

It may not match both clauses of:

```
 db.col.find({$or: [{name: 's'}, {c: 1}]})
```

In a performant manner. So this is something you must bare in mind here with the parallelism of `$or` clauses. If you wish to check that all clauses use indexes you can use an `explain()` on the end which will break down the clauses and their usage for you.

Comment: Is there a way to tell MongoDB this: " Return the first document found by the first clause, and only if no document is found from the first condition use the second" and so on ?

Comment: @Adio Unfortunately not with MongoDB it will just run all clauses in parallel and then return the results, it hasn't got a CASE statement

Comment: so I have to do this in production ?

Comment: @Adio How do you mean? It should be OK to have all clauses run in parallel and you shouldn't (so long as you choose your query carefully and indexes etc) see too much of a performance problem using `$or`